# Migrating from Google Cloud Tools in Eclipse, Google App Engine Java Project to Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tools

Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse is going to become obsolete January 30, 2024 due to its lack of support of Java 11+ and Java 8 will become undeployable. Because of that I am trying to convert from my Eclipse Standard Java App Engine project to using a gradle build file and gcloud app deploy. I added a gradle.build file to the root of the java project that look like this:

```
buildscript {      // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()      // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  } 

   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.5.0'
   }

}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

dependencies {
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
// Add your dependencies here.

}

  appengine {
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
      stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
      promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }
  }


sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

I took this directly from Google's example and remove the gretty and jetty libraries from it, because whenever I tried to build using gradle I would get the error: Could not set unknown property 'baseName' for task ':archiveProduct' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip. I think those libraries are just for running the app locally, so I don't think it's a big deal that I removed them, but let me know if it is.

I also added an app.yaml file that looks like this:

```
runtime: java11
service: serviceName
entrypoint: java -cp "*" packagename.Driver
```

When I was trying to deploy my code the gcloud app deploy command was complaining about a lack of a Main Class so I added one to the project even though I don't think it needs one, because it was working just fine without it on Eclipse. It looks like this:

```
package packageName;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a driver main class.");
    }
}
```

When I deployed it my appengine just give the error Service Unavailable and none of my servlets that were mapped with web.xml work.

I am not sure why google won't just add support for Java 11+ to Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse, but because of that I have to deal with this.

If Someone has any idea how to take a standard java appengine project from Eclipse and deploy it using gradle that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to restructure the folder structure like in the following:

```
your-app-engine-project/
│
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   └── com/
│   │   │       └── example/
│   │   │           └── YourApp.java
│   │   ├── appengine/
│   │   │   ── app.yaml
│   │   └── webapp/
│   │       ├── WEB-INF/
│   │       │   └── appengine-web.xml
│   │       └── index.jsp
├── build.gradle
```

and I changed my app.yaml file to have the following entrypoint instead of my main class entrypoint: java -noverify -jar 'nameofwarfilefrombuild'.war

Put all the war folder files from your eclipse project inside src/main/webapp and all your java code file under src/main/java

Deploy the app using ./gradlew appengineDeploy or gradle appengineDeploy.

Comment: Turns out you don't even need the app.yaml file.